# finding shortest valid path in a colored-edge graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Given a directed graph G, with edges colored either green or purple, and a vertex S in G, I must find an algorithm that finds the shortest path from s to each vertex in **G so the path includes at most two purple edges** (and green as much as needed).

I thought of BFS on G after removing all the purple edges, and for every vertex that the shortest path is still infinity, do something to try to find it, but I'm kinda stuck, and it takes alot of the running time as well...

Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do remove all purple edges if you're allowed to use two? What exactly means 'do something to try to find it'?

Comment: Do you mean "For each vertex v in G, find shortest path from S to v using at most 2 purple edges" ?  Or are you referring to a minimum spanning tree with at most 2 purples ?  Also, regarding paths after removing all purples, many of those won't be the shortest path that includes at most 2 purples.

Comment: @ishtar - It really a long shot, I'm really stuck here.

Comment: @jwpat7 - Each shortest path from S to any v in the graph must not have more than 2 purple edges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicate your graph, so you have G<sub>1</sub>, G<sub>2</sub>, G<sub>3</sub>, such in each graph you redirect purple edges as follows: if (u<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>1</sub>) is a purple edge in G<sub>1</sub>, then change it to (u<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>).

I.e. You have three graphs where each time you take a purple edge it moves you to the next graph, and on G<sub>3</sub> there are no more purple edges. That construction builds the purple restriction into the structure, and will then be enforced automatically.

Now you simply find the shortest path from s to all nodes as usual. With the results you have to choose which is shorter between each path from s to u<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>2</sub>, u<sub>3</sub>.

All in all the construction takes linear time, and the new graph size is O(1) times larger than the original, so APSP takes the same time, and the final run to determine which of the three paths found is shortest is also linear.

Comment: How come that if G3 is a duplicate of G1, how will it remain without any purple edges?

Comment: @user1067083: The purple edges are not copied into G1, G2 or G3, but handled specially, as described in davin's first paragraph.

Comment: @user1067083, that's part of the construction. You redirect purple edges from G1 to G2 and G2 to G3 and remove them from G3.

Answer (score 1):

You need three shortest paths to each vertex: paths with 0, 1 and 2 purple edges.  In your algorithm, you need to store three different path lengths at each vertex.  When you consider an `s-t` path with k purple edges and an edge `t-u`, if the edge is green then the potential `s-t-u` path has k purple edges, and if the `s-t-u` path is shorter than other `s-u` paths with k purple edges, you store its length at slot k of vertex `u`.  Alternatively, if the `t-u` edge is purple, you work with slot k+1 of vertex `u`. Can you work out the rest by yourself?

Comment: @user1067083: I extended the answer a bit.  I've described the approach as an algorithm modification, but it is equivalent to modifying the graph instead... but I don't know if the alternative approach would be any easier to learn.

Comment: Thanks alot for the effort, but I'm failing to understand your idea =\...I'll read it few more times to try to further understand

Answer (score 0):

Note that any path without loops in a graph like yours with `n` vertices can be at most `n-1` long.

Assign length `n` to each purple edge where the `n` is the number of vertices. Find the shortest path from `S` to every other vertex, using, e.g. the Dijkstra algorithm.

Now, examine the path lengths:

1. if the path length is less than `n`, then you have a path of only green edges, since even one purple edge will increase the path length over `n-1`;
2. if the path length is inside `[n, 2n)`, then you have exactly one purple edge, since two or more purple edges will increase the path length over `2n-1`;
3. if the path length is inside `[2n, 3n)`, then you have exactly two purple edges, since three or more purple edges will increase the path length over `3n-1`;
4. otherwise a path with at most two purple edges does not exist.